# Obtener valor desde un input oculto

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un `span` que muestra valores desde un rango noUISlider, de ese `span` quiero tomar el valor que arroja al mover el selector y almacenarlo para usarlo en una operación matemática (multiplicar y o dividir por otro valor) y ese resultado mostrarlo en el sitio

Imagen de referencia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ve que hay un rango mínimo y máximo, ambos valores tendrán una conversión. Por tratarse de un plugin de WordPress, sólo tengo acceso al siguiente código generado en HTML:

```
<div class="price-slider price">
    <span id="price-value-min">9.350</span> 
    <span class="separator">UF </span>
    <span id="price-value-max">38.500</span>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="price_min" id="min-value" value="9.350">
<input type="hidden" name="price_max" id="max-value" value="38.500">
```

Los valores del input cambian al deslizar, son esos valores los que necesito capturar

Actualmente tengo esto, pero no consigo mostrar valor alguno

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    // $ Works! You can test it with next line if you like
    // console.log($);

    $('#price-value-min').click(function() {
        var x = $(this).val();
        // alert(x);

        // Recomiendo usar la consola en lugar de alerts
        console.log('El valor es: ' + x);
    });

});
```

Cabe mencionar que esos valores cambian

Agradecido.

Comment: El input que usas para deslizar es del tipo range?

Comment: No te muestra valor, porque estas intentado activar con el evento "Click", un elemento no clickeable como el "span".
Prueba a utilizar "change"  sobre los elementos hidden. 
algo como :
 $('#min-value').change(function () {  
   console.log($(this).val());
   });

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia así es, pero no lo puedo manipular

Comment: Carlos, no estás identificando bien los elementos, en jQuery, `#` es para el `id`, y ahí tú estás poniendo el valor del atributo `name`. Si lo cambias por: **`$('#min-value').click(function() { //código`**  y por **`$('#max-value').click(function() { //código`** debería funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Captura el valor de **max** y **min** de los **inputs** después que cambie  el `input` que fija el rango:

```
$('#id_input_con_type_range').change(function(){  // si es una clase pondrias  .nombre_de_clase en vez de #id_d_input
      var min =  $('#min-value').val(),
          max = $('#max-value').val()
      console.log('maximo:',max,'minimo:',min)

})
```

> Nota: Si no sabes donde esta el `html` par el `input` de tipo **range**, click derecho sobre el elemento, inspeccionar elemento y fíjate en su **id**.

Comment: Se puede usar con una clase?

Comment: si claro, te actualizo la respuesta, para que veas como

Comment: si es lo que necesitabas recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada, saludos...

Comment: es lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!